# Set image to Html ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ActionResult", new { CustomerId= DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "CustomerId") }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

How can i make html.actionlink as image (set image)

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An `ActionLink` is, pretty much by definition, a link.  The `Html.ActionLink` method you're calling even accepts the text of the link as its first parameter, so you can expect it to be a text link.

But with *slightly* more manual HTML, you can create an `a` tag around an `img` tag using the same target URL.  Just [use `Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470197.aspx) instead of `Html.ActionLink`.  Maybe something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { CustomerId= DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "CustomerId") })" target="_blank">
    <img src="yourImage.png" alt="Image Text" />
</a>
```

Comment: I use devexpress so i need actionlink

Comment: @user2927086: I'm not familiar with DevExpress.  (Nor did you mention it in your question.)  Seems a bit limiting as a toolset if it doesn't allow you to customize your output, though.  In any event, you'll at least want to elaborate on that in your question.  Add a tag for DevExpress, include a more complete code sample, and explain why you are *required* to use `Html.ActionLink`.  (Which, I suspect, you aren't actually *required* to use.)